# insert chinese handwriting keyboard into view of app

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, cjk, handwriting

i would like to sort of embed the chinese handwriting keyboard into a view in my app. That is to say, i don't want it connected to the real keyboard. In fact, I don't even want it visible to the user. I'd like the user to simply be able to handwrite in the center of a blank screen, and have a chinese character output on the screen after completion. is this even possible?

Comment: You mean **[this](http://upload.newhua.com/5/12/1301035585422.jpg)**?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could support handwriting would be to write a view which never became firstResponder (preventing the keyboard from appearing), userInteractionEnabled=YES (to get touches), and uses the touchesMoved to draw the characters as the user moves their finger.

You can implement a custom keyboard by returning a custom keyboard UIView from the `inputView` property on [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) and similar text input views.